# polkit-graphical gui

Tags: policykit

I've recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, very nice, multiboot with Mate-mint, windows and occasionally hacintosh.

The thing which bothers me is that when it asks me password (gui) all other things gets inactive. It is not only on top of others, I cannot do anything else. Mate lets me do other activities, so I click on panel, on my script I made, fill automatically password text, same time.

Is possible to do the same thing with GNOME?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about GUI consistence, polkit agents from different desktop environments could replace each other.

As you mention that mate dialog is model-less (does not lock focus) you can use it.

1. Disable gnome agent autostart by renaming it autostart file.

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop.disabled
   ```
2. Edit mate one to autostart with gnome session too beside mate.

   ```
   ~$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1.desktop

   ...
   OnlyShowIn=MATE;GNOME;
   X-MATE-AutoRestart=true
   X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
   ```

Comment: Also, by skipping the second step, you can disable GUI agent and instead use CUI agent `pkttyagent`.